# Electron: loadURL from buffer

Tags: electron

In my renderer I can emit an event to create a PDF. However, before writing to disk I'd like to first open the newly cerated PDF in another window. How can I circumvent the writing to the file system and use `data` as my source for `loadURL`?

My code so far:

```
ipcMain.on('view-pdf', (event, url) => {
  let pdf
  mainWindow.webContents.printToPDF({}, (error, data) => {
    if (error) throw error
    pdf = data
    // what's the magic here to make pdf work?
  })
  const pdfWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1024,
    height: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      plugins: true,
      webSecurity: false
    }
  })
  pdfWindow.loadURL(pdf)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The async nature of Javascript is a beast. This works as expected:

```
ipcMain.on('view-pdf', (event, url) => {
  mainWindow.webContents.printToPDF({}, (error, data) => {
    if (error) throw error
    const pdf = data.toString('base64')
    const pdfWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 1024,
      height: 800,
      webPreferences: {
        plugins: true,
        webSecurity: false
      }
    })
  pdfWindow.loadURL('data:application/pdf;base64,' + pdf)
  })
})
```

The code is not perfect but this is how it works.

Comment: and it's extremely slow. I think they are working on a better solution in the plf plugin iirc.